# Rspec > testing database views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, rspec

How can database views be tested in Rspec?  Every scenario is wrapped in a transaction and the data does not look like it is being persisted to the database (MySQL in my case).  My view returns with an empty result set because none of the records are being persisted in the transaction.  I am validating that the records are not being stored by setting a debug point in my spec and checking my data with a database client while the spec is being debugged.

The only way I can think to have my view work would be if I could commit the transaction before the end of the scenario and then clear the database after the scenario is complete.  Does anyone know how to accomplish this or is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I got it.  In order to not use transactions, you need to specify:

```
self.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

You also must be sure to clean up what you create after each scenario.

```
describe Attendee do
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  def clear_all
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('delete from users')
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('delete from contact_info')
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('delete from events')
  end

  before(:each) do
    # create some test users
    @event = Factory.create(:event)
    @event.publish!
    @user = Factory.create(:user)
    @user_2 = Factory.create(:user_2)
  end

  after(:each) do
    clear_all
  end

  it "should list have attendees in the directory" do
    # in my case, Attendee class uses my attendees database view
    Attendee.count.should be 2
  end
end
```